# Attaching virtual networks to resource groups in Azure using Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to attach virtual networks to resource groups in Azure using Terraform. The script I have written is attaching a single subnet to a single Azure resource group. However I want to attach multiple virtual networks to maybe one or two resource groups. Just as we do in Azure portal that we create a single resource group and attach multiple vnets to it, I want to achieve the same using Terraform.

I am attaching the script below:

```
/*To generate a uniqueID ; here we are generating unique IDs equal
  to the number of resource groups being created.
*/
resource "random_uuid" "uniqueid" {
  count = var.resource_group_count
}


resource "random_integer" "resource_group_value" {
  min = 0
  max = var.resource_group_count
}
/*
To create a resource group with a unique name by attaching a unique id
 generated from the previous block; here we are creating 'n' resource groups
 and each RG will be appended with one of 'n' unique IDs created from the 
 previous block
*/
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resourcegroup" {
  count = var.resource_group_count
  name     = "TF-${substr(random_uuid.uniqueid[count.index].result,0,7)}-${count.index}"
  location = "South India"
}

/*
 This block will create virtual networks as provided by user input
*/
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "virtualnetwork" {
  count = var.virtualnetwork_count
  name                = "vnet-${count.index}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup[random_integer.resource_group_value.id].location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup[random_integer.resource_group_value.id].name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}
```

I am trying to attach virtual networks to resource groups in Azure using Terraform. The script I have written is attaching a single subnet to a single Azure resource group. However I want to attach multiple virtual networks to maybe one or two resource groups. Just as we do in Azure portal that we create a single resource group and attach multiple vnets to it, I want to achieve the same using Terraform.

Comment: Can you be more specific on how many resource groups you require for this query one or more than one? @Sushmita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried attaching 2 virtual networks with 2 resource groups in Azure using Terraform  I was able to provision the requirement.

In this updated script, the **location** and `resource_group_name` attributes of the `azurerm_virtual_network` resource are set based on the **virtual network** index and the number of resource groups. The % operator is used to ensure that the virtual networks are evenly distributed among the resource groups.

By making these changes, you can attach multiple virtual networks to one or two resource groups using Terraform.
Here for demo purpose I tried to provision 2 **Resource Groups** with 2 **vNets** each

**My Terraform Configuration:**

```
# Define the number of resource groups and virtual networks per group
variable "resource_group_count" {
  description = "Number of resource groups to create"
  type        = number
  default     = 2
}

variable "virtualnetworks_per_group" {
  description = "Number of virtual networks per resource group"
  type        = number
  default     = 2
}

# Generate unique IDs for resource groups
resource "random_uuid" "uniqueid" {
  count = var.resource_group_count
}

# Create resource groups
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resourcegroup" {
  count = var.resource_group_count
  name     = "RG-${substr(random_uuid.uniqueid[count.index].result, 0, 7)}"
  location = "East US"
}

# Create virtual networks
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "virtualnetwork" {
count = var.resource_group_count * var.virtualnetworks_per_group
name                = "vnet-${count.index}"
location            = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup[floor(count.index / var.virtualnetworks_per_group)].location
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup[floor(count.index / var.virtualnetworks_per_group)].name
address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Vinay B............got to know something really beneficial